# ASP.net GridView Margins

Tags: asp.net, css

How can I set the margin-left property of the HTML table generated from an ASP.net GridView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView id="hurfDurf" style="margin-left:10%;" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

Alternatively, at the top of your aspx page...

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #hurfDurf table
    {
        margin-left:10px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: Hur?  I'm not wrapping anything in a div.